# Can I get or set user thumbnail photo using Azure AD REST API?

Tags: rest, powershell, azure, azure-active-directory

I'd like to manage active directory user's thumbnail photos using Azure REST API. It can be Azure Active Directory REST API, Exchange Online REST API, Unified Graph API. Any of those.

Unfortunately the object that is returned from graph API does not contain photo data. And $link references did not work for me either.

Any ideas?

Regards,
Dmitry

Comment: Were you able to find a way to do this, Pyro? Thanks.

Comment: for anyone landing on this circa 2021. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/profilephoto-get?view=graph-rest-1.0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can. Try this:

```
HTTP GET https://graph.windows.net/<directory_name_or_id>/users/<users_upn_or_objectid>/thumbnailPhoto"
```

Comment: Using that URL I get 404.